# Passing Values from Client Side to Server side via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a question regarding passing values from client side to server side using hidden fields. for example I have a list box and I need to get the values of the selected items in the list box after looping on the values I'm storing them in hidden field and reading it from the code behind.

Is it okay to use that logic? I know that the values are expose to the client if you viewing the source page. 
Is there any other way? Or should I keep using the same logic?

Thanks.

Comment: why would you need a client to send you data they shouldn't be able to see?

Comment: I'm asking is it safe to pass data through hidden fields?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid method of getting things done. If they can already choose/view things from the list box, what's the harm of them being able to see it in View Source?

Comment: if the value is something the user should not be able to know (in any manner) then don't ship it, hidden or otherwise. if you don't mind them seeing it, ship it hidden, but know that they CAN find it if they want.

Comment: I'm using method to pass sensitive information though session file which is completely hidden from the end user. I just want to make sure that passing information that not sensitive through hidden field is right thing to do.